# ngOnDestroy and $('#element').foundation('destroy');

Tags: javascript, angular, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I'm trying to implement a Sticky Magellan in my Angular2 application. Once I leave the view I want to remove the plugin, because otherwise I get problems when I'm revisiting the view.

So I'm using:

```
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    $('#element').foundation('destroy');
  }
```

Which results in:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: We're sorry, 'destroy'
>   is not an available method for this element. ReferenceError: We're
>   sorry, 'destroy' is not an available method for this element.
>       at jQuery.fn.init.foundation (eval at webpackJsonp.67.module.exports
>   (http://localhost:4200/scripts.bundle.js:156:8), :294:15)
>       at ComplexDetailsComponent.webpackJsonp.502.ComplexDetailsComponent.ngOnDestroy
>   (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:1564:26)
>       at Wrapper_ComplexDetailsComponent.ngOnDestroy (/AppModule/ComplexDetailsComponent/wrapper.ngfactory.js:13:16)
>       at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_ComplexDetailsComponent_Host0.destroyInternal
>   (/AppModule/ComplexDetailsComponent/host.ngfactory.js:38:37)
>       at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.destroy (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:104561:14)
>       at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.destroy (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:104964:38)
>       at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detachAndDestroy (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:104545:14)
>       at ComponentRef_.destroy (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:46645:70)
>       at RouterOutlet.deactivate (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:88910:28)
>       at ActivateRoutes.deactiveRouteAndOutlet (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:26420:20)
>       at ActivateRoutes.deactiveRouteAndItsChildren (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:26380:18)
>       at ActivateRoutes.deactivateRoutes (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:26295:22)
>       at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:26257:19
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at ActivateRoutes.deactivateChildRoutes (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:26256:29)
>       at resolvePromise (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:7055:31) [angular]
>       at resolvePromise (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:7026:17) [angular]
>       at http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:7103:17 [angular]
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:33595:37) [angular]
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:6756:36) [angular]
>       at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:6556:47) [ =>
>   angular]
>       at drainMicroTaskQueue (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:6936:35) []
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:6814:25) []
>   ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:60 next @
>   application_ref.js:348 schedulerFn @ async.js:93
>   SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:234 SafeSubscriber.next @
>   Subscriber.js:183 Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125 Subscriber.next
>   @ Subscriber.js:89 Subject.next @ Subject.js:55 EventEmitter.emit @
>   async.js:79 NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:333 onHandleError @
>   ng_zone.js:294 ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:338 Zone.runGuarded
>   @ zone.js:142
>   _loop_1 @ zone.js:557 drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:566 ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:424 zone.js:522

Has anyone come across this before?

**Update 1**

Calling `$('#element').foundation('destroy');` in the console works. And foundation is initialised at the time I call `$('#element').foundation('destroy');` in `ngOnDestroy()`.

**Update 2**

I'm using version *6.2.4* of Foundation

**Update 3**

Please see also: [Foundation Sticky element in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43098821/foundation-sticky-element-in-angular2)

Comment: What version of foundation are you using?

Comment: It's version  '6.2.4'

Comment: Maybe you're initializing Foundation after trying to call `$('#element').foundation('destroy');` Try executing `$('#element').foundation('destroy');` in console and see what it happens.

Comment: It works in the console. I've the feeling that the l `$('#element').foundation('destroy');`  and the `ngOnDestroy` don't really work nicely together.

Comment: I guess the element is being added after the foundation is initialized. Try manually call `$('#element').foundation()` to reinitialize it on `ngAfterViewInit` for instance... just for testing purposes

Comment: Yes. The Sticky behaviour is also fine. But only on first page load. I've leave the page and open it with a different entry the Sticky and the Magellan fail.

I tried to call `$('#element').foundation()` and this is the response:
_Tried to initialize magellan on an element that already has a Foundation plugin._

Comment: Do you have any idea why it is working on page refresh and not afterwards anymore?