# Foundation 6 Sticky element in Angular2

Tags: jquery, angular, zurb-foundation, angular-cli

This question builds on one of my earlier questions: [ngOnDestroy and $('#element').foundation('destroy');](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43088931/ngondestroy-and-element-foundationdestroy) I'm basically trying to make Foundations Sticky work in my Angular2 application. Apart of the issue that I can't destroy the Foundation element, using `ngOnDestroy()`, I struggle with the Sticky element in general. What I have is this:

> Component Template

```
<div id="wrapperDiv">
        <div class="columns medium-2 no-pad-left" data-sticky-container>
          <div id="myStickyElement" class="sticky" data-sticky data-top-anchor="wrapperDiv">
            <aside>
              <ul class="menu vertical">
                <li><a href="#elm1">Elm1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#eml2">Eml2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#eml3">Eml3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#eml4">Eml4</a></li>
              </ul>
            </aside>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

It might be important to say that `wrapperDiv` is loaded directly and has no `ngIf` condition in its parents.

In my component I use this in my `ngAfterViewInit`:

> Component

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    $('#myStickyElement').foundation();
  }
```

When I do a *full page reload* on this specific view, everything is super and works! If I navigate to this view, it doesn't work. Seems to be related with the *full page reload*

On some point I was creating the Sticky element like this:

```
let myStickyElement = new Foundation.Sticky($('#myStickyElement'));
```

Which did not have any impact on the behaviour, but I could print out the object `myStickyElement`.

On full page reload the object looks like this:
[image]

And here if I navigate to the page:

[image]

As you can see, the object of `myStickyElement` looks way different. Something is missing. Has anyone come across this problem before? Why is the full page reload so much different?

Comment: this is strage, angular should call `ngAfterViewInit` on page reload AND on rout navigation. please take a look at this plunker adabted from angular tour of heros. I added log statements to all three components inside `ngAfterViewInit`. Please open console and navigate between "heros" and "dashboard" rout, you'll see that `ngAfterViewInit` is indeed called as I described. https://plnkr.co/edit/Z0MMz5z1PVGnzIsicypV?p=preview

Comment: It is calling the `ngAfterViewInit`, but Foundation seems to behave different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using this:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    $('#myStickyElement').foundation();
}
```

is the correct move, however, for some reason the sticky plugin is not working. The plugin attaches a data object `zfPlugin` that has an api to enable 'stickyness'

here is how you do it:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    $('#myStickyElement').foundation();
    $('#myStickyElement').data("zfPlugin")._setSticky();
}
```

I set up a plnkr here that shows this working: https://plnkr.co/edit/zPuXooHYsJHuOQUj6Rdd?p=preview

**UPDATE 1**

After looking at the foundation code here: https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/blob/develop/js/foundation.sticky.js specifically this block:

```
$(window).one('load.zf.sticky', function(){
...
}
```

The sticky plugin is waiting for an event `load.zf.sticky` to be triggered, it happens in static pages because foundation knows those elements are on the page. Since it's in angular component, you have to trigger that event yourself.

I have updated the plunkr here: https://plnkr.co/edit/1P6oU5ZrdKHGlMeHYUUw?p=preview

here are the updates I made:

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    $('#myStickyElement').foundation();
    $(window).trigger('load.zf.sticky');
  }
```

**Note**: in html I added `data-sticky-on="small"`

Comment: Great stuff @ahmed-musallam! It works almost. Now it becomes Sticky also if I just navigate to the page, but it doesn't stick to `wrapperDiv`. It sticks to the header, which is also Sticky, but a different sticky element. It seems like it is making the `data-sticky-container` fixed or Sticks it to the header or makes it _fixed_? Again, it works if I do a full page reload on that page it work perfectly fine.